# Loading a file and displaying it on a window on hover jQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, file, load

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Two columns, one one there's a list of articles (links) and on the right there's a window.

Each link leads to its own page, so I want to see if its possible to show in the window on the right a few lines of the article, to provide an idea what it's about.

Ideally, when the user hovers over a link, javascript/jQuery will look up the file and display it.

Right now I have the links working and on hover they show whatever text I already set up in the page itself. So the show on mouseover works, I just need to know if there's a way to dynamically load stuff during hover.

I've seen something similar done in forums and emails in the form of tooltips that show the content of the link.

For further information, the articles are the same page, each article is its own file with that gets pasted into it through '/?id=C1' and php.

This is that I have working now:
LINK:

```
<a onMouseOver="changeText('La canción verde', 'C1.php')" 
href="?id=C1" alt="La canción verde" title="La canción verde" >
1. La canción verde</a>
```

FUNCTION, the div where the blurb would appear is "descripciondecuentos":

```
<script>
function changeText(msg, documento)
{ document.getElementById("descripciondecuentos").innerHTML=msg; }
</script>
```

Perfect world, this function would do something with 'documento' and change "descripciondecuentos." Not sure if it would be wise to load up all those files during page load, as that would just bloat the page.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into jQuery's `load()` function.

For example:

```
$("a.fetchContent").hover(function() {
    var newLoadedHtml = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#sectionContainer").fadeOut("fast")
        .load(newLoadedHtml + " #content")
        .fadeIn("slow");
});
```

and your HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
  <a class="fetchContent"  href="includes/Pages1.html" title="Pages 1">Pages 1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="fetchContent"  href="includes/Pages2.html" title="Pages 2">Pages 2</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="fetchContent"  href="includes/Pages3.html" title="Pages 3">Pages 3</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="fetchContent"  href="includes/Pages4.html" title="Pages 4">Pages 4</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

The href of your links should be relative paths to your HTML files (or php files) such as: `includes/Pages1.html`. The load function allows you to only load a part of the page you are calling ( `+ " #content"`).

Comment: This is kind of working. The right files are loading but fading in and out repeatedly. Also, is there a way to exclude some <a> from this function? Now all links are loading into the box, not just the list.

Comment: EDIT: got the <a> tags under control by giving them a unique ID and having the function look for that instead. Since no other <a> has ids, it worked. That also solved some formatting problems. One thing still wonky is that hovering from one to the other is sometimes weird, showing the previous hover instead of current. But this is not always, so looking more into it. THANKS for the help, by the way.

Comment: By adding a class only to the links for which this is necessary. (I edited it).

Comment: Excellent. I got it working (I think), minor CSS playing around should do it. The only current problem is that the file displayed is sometimes showing the previous file hovered, but that only happens when my <a> tags are on top of each other and there is no "rest" between hovers/loads. Added a <br /> to give it more breathing room and it behaves. Some minor CSS should make it prettier. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: To make sure that your links not overlap, give them a display: block and a fixed height! (If the answer was correct, please mark it as such by clicking the "check".)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's mouseover function on your link like this :

```
$('#link').mouseover(function() {
});
```

And to load stuff dynamically you can use ajax inside that function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "Your text Url"
}).done(function ( data ) {
  display the data
});
```

more about ajax : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/